# How do I add a number onto all the values of a map?

Tags: kotlin

This is my first language, so I don't understand Kotlin syntax all that well, and I don't know many of the function names.

[Tried adding 1 to the values of the map, didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7cwJ.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please check documentation and examples of `forEachIndexed`. As a new member of Stackoverflow please read [ask].